# Update: program shows adress of fstream instead of the text file

Tags: c++, string, pointers, ifstream

I am about to write a program which asks the user if they want to "search or convert" a file, if they choose `convert`, they need to provide the location of the file.

I do not know why the program shows the address of the file instead of opening it.

Here is my first approach:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char dateiname[64], kommando[64];

    ifstream iStream;


    cout << "Choose an action: " << endl <<
            " s - search " << endl <<
            " c - convert" << endl <<
            " * - end program" << endl;
    cin.getline(kommando,64,'\n');
    switch(kommando[0])
    {
        case 'c':
            cout << "Enter a text file: " << endl;
            cin.getline(dateiname,64,'\n');
            iStream.open("C://users//silita//desktop//schwarz.txt");
        case 's': break;
        case '*': return 0;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid command: " << kommando << endl;
    }
    if (!iStream)
    {
         cout << "The file " << dateiname << " does not exist." << endl;
    }
    string s;
    while (getline(iStream, s)) {
        while(s.find("TIT", 0) < s.length())
            s.replace(s.find("TIT", 0), s.length() - s.find("TIT", 3),"*245$a");
        cout << iStream << endl;
    }    
    iStream.close();
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the strings mean, in English. Could you add comments?

Comment: string s intends to replace all "TIT" (which represents a category, found in the text file which the user enters) with the sign "500$a" , so this program is made to replace specific sings in a text file

Comment: You explained the part that was most obvious. I guess I should have specified I meant you should translate the German(?) words in the strings you `cout`. Sometimes people can guess (like "Konvertieren" sounds like "convert"), but this may be hard for some people. Some phrases, like "Nicht gefunden" are impossible to guess.

Comment: You are absolutely right,  "Konvertieren" means "convert", "Suchen" means to search and "Date nicht gefunden" means that the file does not exist/ could not have been found. This is my actual code (above), the problem is still that the program ends before the user can enter the adress of the text file

Comment: uploaded it in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Lassie's answer, you can't compare strings in this way using c or c++; just to flesh it out, however, I'll explain *why*.

```
char MyCharArr[] = "My Character Array"
// MyCharArr is now a pointer to MyCharArr[0], 
// meaning it's a memory address, which will vary per run 
// but we'll assume to be 0x00325dafa   
if( MyCharArr == "My Character Array" ) {
    cout << "This will never be run" << endl;
}
```

Here the if compares a pointer (MyCharArr) which will be a memory address, ie an integer, to a character array literal. Obviously 0x00325dafa != "My Character Array".

Using cstrings (character arrays), you need to use the `strcmp()` function which you will find in the `cstring` library, which will give you a number telling you "how different" the strings are, essentially giving the difference a numerical value. In this instance we are only interested in *no difference*, which is 0, so what we need is this:

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char MyCharArr[] = "My Character Array"
if( strcmp(MyCharArr,"My Character Array")==0 ) { 
    // If there is 0 difference between the two strings...
    cout << "This will now be run!" << endl;
}
```

While you are not doing so in your question, If we were using c++ strings rather than character arrays, we would use the `compare()` method to similar affect:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string MyString = "My C++ String"
if( MyString.compare("My C++ String")==0 ) { 
    // If there is 0 difference between the two strings...
    cout << "This will now be run!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: My next problem is that my program ends right after the program asks the user to put in the adress of the text file. Do you know what is my fault there? thank you

Answer (score 2):

At first you can't compare c-strings using `==`. You must use `strcmp(const char*, const char*)`. More info about it you can find there: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/
For example: `if (i == "Konvertieren")` must become `if(!strcmp(i,"Konvertieren"))`